# Can Comma be used for introducing a substitute?

Tags: grammar, nouns

Example: But it was your barbaric friends, the huns, the ones that caused so much damage to the world.

Can Comma be used to introduce substitute(s) for the subject?

Comment: Not only can commas be used in this way, they are *mandatory* in the case of what is called a [non-restrictive appositive](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/appositive/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

(Extra text here to make the answer long enough to submit.)